# How to validate dynamic web content in a dropdown list using selenium?

Tags: selenium, xpath, testng

Just for curiosity I was testing an application and trying to automate it. I was testing Momondo.in where I wanted to validate the outputs displayed in the list but the contents are in strange format how am I suppose to handle such kinds of elements. Just for example you can go to the website and type "b" in the 'From' option we get 6 options in form of list now I want to save all of them in a ArrayList in JAVA and then check if the first element is 'b' or it contains '-b' or not for validation thanks for help in advance.

Comment: Share html code and what you have tried so far.

Comment: Which _Selenium Language Binding Art_ are you using? _Java_ / _Python_ / _C#_ / _NodeJS_ ?

Answer (score 1):

```
driver.get("https://www.momondo.in/");

driver.findElement(By.cssSelector(".searchFormWrapper  input[name='origin']"))
    .sendKeys("b");

Thread.sleep(2000);

List<WebElement> options = driver.findElements(
          By.cssSelector("div[id*='origin-smartbox-dropdown'] ul > li"));

for(WebElement opt:options) {

    String airPortCode = opt.getAttribute("data-apicode");

    String airPortShortName = opt.getAttribute("data-short-name");

    String airPortFullName = opt.getText();

    // It's up to you to determine to check which one of 
    // `airPortCode`, `airPortShortName`, `airPortFullName` includes `b`

}
```

Comment: Simple and perfect answer